# Admin Custom Meta Box - Pull Last 5 Posts from Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query

This is what I'm trying to accomplish, I have a custom post type of "demos", from here I can add custom CSS/HTML/JS to display a demonstration (online preview) of what it is I have designed/coded. (This part works great)

First I go in and create the demo and publish it, then I create a new post about the element I have designed/coded and add details through custom fields such as Name, Browser Compatibility, Framework, Files Included, etc.

On this page I display the tutorial and details about the element and also provide 2 buttons, "Download" & "Live Demo".
I am able to use the "Download" button linked to the attached file just fine (this works).

[image: Buttons]

Right now I am using a blank textbox for the "Live Demo" this is where I type in the Live Demo URL which links within the post to the Demo.  What I want to do is be able to just select the Demo Post Title through a SelectBox instead of typing the URL in. Meta Box that retrieves Last 5 Posts from Custom Post Type Demos?

Like this:

[image: Meta Box]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're looking for information or solution but [this post](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) might help you, especially the "Building a custom post meta box" section.

The callback function is actually what you need. In this callback you need to run a loop that get posts from your Custom Post Type `Demos` and populate it into a HTML `select` element with specific values.